# MATLAB - Axes Relabeling trouble-- axes not relabeled, but compiles fine

Tags: matlab, syntax, axes

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]I have to rescale my axes. I did the necessary calculations to rescale the axes, and tried using xlim([,]) and  axis([])

the code runs fine and correctly loads the images into plots, but doesn't rescale the axes at all.

xlim ([ lower_val, upper_val]); ylim([lower_val, upper_val]);  and  axis ([ l_x u_x l_y u_x); 
after the figure was created
and after the image was graphed

and for all tries, I'm not getting a change in the axes for my image-plot.

```
brightfield= figure(1);

 %10x objective
 %Lpixel=(tot_mag)*(Lrealinimage);
 %Lreal=(#pixels*Lpixel)/tot_mag;
 %Lrealx=(1280*3.6)/(10*0.5);
 %Lrealx=921.6000

 axis([0 921.6000, 0 737.2800]);
 xlim ([0, 921.6000]); ylim([0, 737.2800]); 

 color_brightfield=imread('cheek_cell_10x.bmp');
 imagesc(color_brightfield);
 axis image; hold on;
 axis([0 921.6000, 0 737.2800]);
 xlim ([0, 921.6000]); ylim([0, 737.2800]); 

title('BrightField Microscopy -> 10x objective');
 xlabel('microns'); ylabel('microns');


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkviA.jpg
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkviA.jpg is  the output image

Comment: Firstly, you only need the `axis(...)` command *or* the `xlim/ylim` commands, not both. Having both is just redundant. Secondly, I can't reproduce this behavior (not in R2016 anyway). Is there more of your actual code where you are making changes to the figure or axes, plotting other things, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

this was run on R2018b - academic version. For some reason it was having a lot of problems the past two days, just saving files and not running stuff that I wrote correctly. I ended up copying and pasting the segment and renamed the .m file and it ran as intended.